# Equivalent mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse m2e command

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I have a Maven error like the following in Eclipse for a Maven project.:

```
Project 'project1' is missing required library: '.../.m2/repository/.../project2/0.37.0-SNAPSHOT/project2-0.37.0-SNAPSHOT.jar'  
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved
```

The error is wrong, because in the parent `pom.xml` version `0.38.0-SNAPSHOT` is defined, which also lies in the `.m2` repository as `project2-0.38.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

I tried: "Right click" -> "Maven" -> "Update Project...", but it does now solve the problem.

Then I tried: `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse`, which solved the problem. But, then the problem is, that it converts the Eclipse Maven project to an Eclipse project. So I have to manually convert it back to an Eclipse Maven project. I also wonder because [Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin is RETIRED](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html).

Is there another solution to the above Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your error messages sais something about 0.37.0-SNAPSHOT but in your text you refere to 0.38.0-SNAPSHOT. Is it a mistake or maybe the version in your dependency is wrong?

First your are right not to mix `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and eclipse-m2e plug-in. Second the Maven->Update Project should fix any misconfiguration.

I would suggest to call `mvn clean install` in your console to verify that there are no real dependency problems. Eclipse sometimes does not update its index correctly.

Second if the error still appears try to restart your eclipse. I often saw that eclipse-m2e does cache some stra

Comment: "Your error messages sais something about 0.37.0-SNAPSHOT but in your text you refere to 0.38.0-SNAPSHOT. Is it a mistake or maybe the version in your dependency is wrong?" No, it is correct. The problem is it should look for `0.38.0-SNAPSHOT`, which would be correct. So I had no error message. Also I have done `mvn clean install` in `project2`.

Comment: What is the output of calling `mvn clean install` in projet1? The error sais that project1 depends on Version `0.37.0-SNAPSHOT` of project2. Hence it seems like project1 is misconfigured.